# iOS Firebase CrashlyticsKit not setting user ID

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to set a user ID for Firebase Crashlytics reports.

Currently I send a user ID only if it's not sent or is changed (very rare event). And there is no user ID in crash reports.

My code:

```
 + (void)setCrashlyticsUserData:(User *)user
{
    if (user == nil) { return; }
    NSString *userIdKey = @"CRASHLYTICS_SENT_USER_ID";
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults;
    NSInteger sentUserId = [userDefaults integerForKey:userIdKey];
    if (sentUserId == user.userId) { return; }

    [CrashlyticsKit setUserIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", user.userId]];
    [userDefaults setInteger:user.userId forKey:userIdKey];
}
```

If this line is commented `if (sentUserId == user.userId) { return; }` I receive a user ID in crash reports.

Should I call `[CrashlyticsKit setUserIdentifier:]` every app launch? I can't find any information about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom attributes of Crashlytics (like custom keys or user identifier) works in log-style in per-session basis.
So, you should call setUserIdentifier in each app session as early as possible.
See this link for code example:

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[Crashlytics setUserIdentifier:]` to provide an id number, token, or hashed value that uniquely identifies the end-user of your application without disclosing or transmitting any of their personal information. You can also clear the value by setting it to a blank string. This value is displayed right in the Crashlytics dashboard.

```
[CrashlyticsKit setUserIdentifier:@"123456789"]; //User ID
```

Or another option is setthe custom key using `[CrashlyticsKit setObjectValue:forKey:]`, See the following example.

```
[CrashlyticsKit setIntValue:3 forKey:@"userid"];
[CrashlyticsKit setObjectValue:@"logged_in" forKey:@"last_UI_action"];
```

See this document for more information.

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html

Comment: I've read the doc. My question was should I call `[CrashlyticsKit setUserIdentifier:]` every app launch

Comment: yes, you can call  [CrashlyticsKit setUserIdentifier:] every app launch